# Adding Facebook SDK to Android Studios Project? (Getting Error 8)

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, android-studio, dependencies

I'm trying to use the FACEBOOK SDK with my android project in android studios.

I've imported the path by clicking on File > Import Module > Source Directory

The path is to the unzipped Facebook SDK folder.

Once entering 'finish' I get the following error:

> Error:(8, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':FriendPickerSample'.

I searched on StackOverFlow and found out that I need to add the following code to the Root directory "***gradle.properties***"

> ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=19
>    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=19.1.0
>    ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=19
>    ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=14

Unfortunately I have no clue where the root directory "gradle.properties" is in Android Studios?

Furthermore, I'm getting this message on top of my Android Studio which I know is related to the error, the message is:

*"Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly"*

How do I get rid of this error, and if the solution is to add code to the Root directory "gradle.proerties"...where is it located?

Answer (score 1):

try using maven repo for the facebook sdk

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0'
```

in your build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0'
}
```